# Calculate Numerator and determinator in Mutate R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this table for example in R:

| A10 | B100 |
| --- | --- |
| -3 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 2 | -4 |

And I have 10,000 of this row.

I am trying to compute:

```
df$Result = (GREATEST(1,[A10]+1)) / (GREATEST(1,[B100]+1))
```

For the numerator: `(GREATEST(1,[A10]+1))`

If `[A10]+1` is less than 1, then you should use 1 for the numerator, else use `[A10]+1`.

For the denominator: `(GREATEST(1,[B100]+1))`

If `[B100]+1` is less than 1, then you should use 1 for the denominator else use `[B100]+1`.

How do I code this mutate R? There are over 10 combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pmax` to get `(GREATEST(1,[A10]+1))` and the same for denominator/

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(result = pmax(1, A10 + 1) / pmax(1, B100 + 1))
df

#  A10 B100 result
#1  -3    0    1.0
#2   0    1    0.5
#3   0    1    0.5
#4   2   -4    3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get this problem done would be using `ifelse()` function as follows

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
        mutate(result = (ifelse(1 > A10 + 1, 1, A10 +1))/(ifelse(1 > B100 + 1, 1, B100 +1)))
```